# How do i update opengl lightning equation in my fragment shader to make my texture less glossy and more like a fabric

Tags: android, textures, rendering, opengl-es, normal-mapping

I built a model in blender, and am currently trying to import it into my android app using assimp together with opengl, i dont have any issues with the importing but my goal is to make the object look realistic as possible, and this is where my problem lies...I have implemented normal mapping using both the diffuse and normals of my texture but after rendering it the objects looks smooth and glossy, yes the bumps were rendered well and i like it but i need the material to look more like a fabric (cloth/textile), please how can i do this? do i need to update my lighting equation or the issue is with my original diffuse texture?

*Here is my original diffuse texture*

[image]

*Here is my rendered model*
[image]

*Here's my fragment shader*

```
    void main()
{
    // obtain normal from normal map in range [0,1]
    vec3 normal = texture2D( normalMap, textureCoords ).xyz;
    // transform normal vector to range [-1,1]
    normal = normalize(normal * 2.0 - 1.0);  // this normal is in tangent space

    // get diffuse color
    vec3 color = texture2D( textureSampler, textureCoords ).xyz;
    // ambient
    vec3 ambient = 0.1 * color;
    // diffuse
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(tangentLightPos - tangentFragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(lightDir, normal), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * color;
    // specular
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(tangentViewPos - tangentFragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    vec3 halfwayDir = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(normal, halfwayDir), 0.0), 32.0);
    vec3 specular = vec3(0.2) * spec;

   gl_FragColor  = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0);
}
```

*Here's my vertex shader*

```
mat3 transpose(mat3 m) {
    return mat3(m[0][0], m[1][0], m[2][0],
    m[0][1], m[1][1], m[2][1],
    m[0][2], m[1][2], m[2][2]);
}

void main()
{

    gl_Position     = mvpMat * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);

    vec3 fragPos = vec3(model * vec4(vertexPosition,1.0));

    vec3 T = normalize(normalMatrix * tangent);
    vec3 N = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    T = normalize(T - dot(T, N) * N);
    vec3 B = cross(N, T);

    mat3 TBN = transpose(mat3(T, B, N));

    //values for fragment shader
    tangentLightPos = TBN * lightPos;
    tangentViewPos  = TBN * viewPos;
    tangentFragPos  = TBN * fragPos;
    textureCoords   = vertexUV;
}
```

Comment: It might help to show the shader code & lighting equation you're using now, as well as the normal map you're using.

Comment: Thanks @DMGregory for your reply, have updated my question